# Typescript Convert Union to intersection

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
enum keyEnum {
    firstKey = 1,
    secKey = 2,
    thirdKey = 3
};

enum firstPropEnum {
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b',
};

enum secPropEnum {
    c = 'c',
    d = 'd',
};

type firstAndSecPropEnum = firstPropEnum | secPropEnum;

type keyPropObj = {
    [keyEnum.firstKey]: { prop: firstPropEnum },
    [keyEnum.secKey]: { prop: secPropEnum },
    [keyEnum.thirdKey]: { prop: firstAndSecPropEnum },
};

type getKeyProp<T extends keyEnum> = keyPropObj[T]['prop'];

type getKeyPropResult1 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey | keyEnum.secKey> // Result secPropEnum | firstPropEnum
// Expected Result secPropEnum.
type getKeyPropResult2 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey | keyEnum.firstKey> // Result firstPropEnum | secPropEnum
// Expected Result firstPropEnum.
type getKeyPropResult3 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.secKey | keyEnum.firstKey> // Result firstPropEnum | secPropEnum
// Expected Result never;
```

So i was expecting to get an intersection rather than a union.
The Result should be a value that in common among all the resulting props.
Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [can convert unions to intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218) with TS2.8 and above.  In your case I'd probably do something like this:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

// use Lookup<T, K> instead of T[K] in cases where the compiler 
//  cannot verify that K is a key of T
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;

type getKeyProp<T extends keyEnum> = Lookup<UnionToIntersection<keyPropObj[T]>, 'prop'>;
```

And the types you want fall out as desired:

```
type getKeyPropResult1 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey | keyEnum.secKey> // secPropEnum.
type getKeyPropResult2 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey | keyEnum.firstKey> // firstPropEnum.
type getKeyPropResult3 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.secKey | keyEnum.firstKey> // never.
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Well could we also do `Lookup<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K]` for better intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always intersect the types yourself:

```
type getKeyPropResult1 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey> & getKeyProp<keyEnum.secKey>
type getKeyPropResult2 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey> & getKeyProp<keyEnum.firstKey>
type getKeyPropResult3 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.secKey> & getKeyProp<keyEnum.firstKey>
```

---

A rather ugly alternative that works for up to 6 keys:

```
type getKeyPropSingle<T extends keyEnum> = keyPropObj[T]['prop'];
type getKeyProp<
    T1 extends keyEnum | null = null,
    T2 extends keyEnum | null = null,
    T3 extends keyEnum | null = null,
    T4 extends keyEnum | null = null,
    T5 extends keyEnum | null = null,
    T6 extends keyEnum | null = null,
> = (T1 extends keyEnum ? getKeyPropSingle<T1> : unknown) &
    (T2 extends keyEnum ? getKeyPropSingle<T2> : unknown) &
    (T3 extends keyEnum ? getKeyPropSingle<T3> : unknown) &
    (T4 extends keyEnum ? getKeyPropSingle<T4> : unknown) &
    (T5 extends keyEnum ? getKeyPropSingle<T5> : unknown) &
    (T6 extends keyEnum ? getKeyPropSingle<T6> : unknown);

type second = getKeyProp<keyEnum.secKey>;
type getKeyPropResult1 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey, keyEnum.secKey>
type getKeyPropResult2 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.thirdKey, keyEnum.firstKey>
type getKeyPropResult3 = getKeyProp<keyEnum.secKey, keyEnum.firstKey>
```

Comment: I was looking for a more scalable approach. Is there a way to iterate over the enum and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @AmolGupta: There probably is no clean solution, at least i know of none. Added another option that works around the [lack of variadic generics](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) to some degree.

Comment: @AmolGupta: Interesting that this is actually possible, but to be honest i would neither write such code nor recommend using it. Conditional types in combination with mapped types are hardly readable and difficult to understand.